# Directing the output of a python code to msqldb table

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to direct a huge amount of output generated on the fly from python to mysql table.I have successfully established a connection from python to mysqldb, I also have the code running smoothly. The issue now is, how do I direct the output to the dbase table?

Example:

Connection to dbase:

```
import MySQLdb
# connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="xxxxxxx",
db="world")
cursor = db.cursor()
```

Code whose output needs to be transferred:

```
val=xrange(1,1000,2)
for x in val:
    print x
```

I'm not used to working with python and mysql at the same time. I can work with them separately, but not as a single unit.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import MySQLdb
# connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="xxxxxxx", db="world")
cursor = db.cursor()

for x in xrange(1,1000,2):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table (mynumber) VALUES(' + str(x) + ');')
```

Something like this? or?

A good idea is also to use `.executemany()` because it doesn't choke the database to much.

- http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#id11 (Ctrl+F -> "executemany")

Another note to take into account is the fact that `values = xrange(1,1000,2)` is slower than doing `for x in xrange(1,1000,2):` because you don't need to wait for `xrange()` to deliver the values before looping through them, doing `for x in xrange()` will cause you to execute whatever it is you want to execute on each given number as they are generated.

Comment: Hi Torxed, thanks for your response, however, I got the following error message:OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"). Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tiger1 Basic database issue 101, my example is trying to place 1 number into a table.
This assume that you have a table that looks like:

`CREATE tablename (test INT);`.  Try my edit.

Comment: Many thanks to you Torxed, its working fine now. Although the column I used was personID, not mynumber as I didn't create mynumber. Thanks once more.

Comment: @Tiger1 You're welcome, and since you didn't give any information about your database what so ever i just winged it :) glad it's working tho! And good luck on your endavours!